# WIX get computer name?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

How can I get the name of the computer on which MSI is executed to populate a control?

I used `[ComputerName]` and `[COMPUTERNAME]` property but it's not working.

Comment: It seems you've got clear answer at wix-users list...

Comment: Here is the link to the wix-users answer: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Get-computer-name-td6205253.html

Answer (score 1):

In customaction print session["ComputerName"] and check what is it printing.

This property should work. Am using the same property and it's working fine for me. Can you please post the code here, if the answer I gave is not working.

Comment: Finaly i got it workign as below: <CustomAction Id="SetMachineName" Property="MACHINENAME" Value="[ComputerName]"></CustomAction>. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found [ComputerName] worked when after setting my Wix Installer version to the correct version of 5.0 for Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. I also conditionally check the host os so I know this will work.

`<Package InstallerVersion="500" Platform="x64" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />`


`<Condition Message="This application is only supported on 64bit Windows Server 2008 sp2 or later.">
<![CDATA[Installed OR ((VersionNT64 >= 600 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT64 >= 601))]]>
</Condition>`